# When to extend from Exception and when to extend from Error in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am writing custom exceptions/errors in Scala and I want to know when I should extend from `Exception` and when I should extend from `Error`?

Comment: Same as in Java, so just read the javadocs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, Error is for internal issues - OutOfMemoryError, etc.  Exceptions are for code-level issues.

Since Scala follows a similar pattern, e.g. `NotImplementedError` extends `Error` and `ScalaReflectionException` extends `Exception`, you should apply the same rule to your code and only extend Exception.